# How to read a complete Unicode code point as String?

Tags: java

I tried this so far:

```
public String readchar (Reader input) throws java.io.IOException
{
  int i16 = input.read(); // UTF-16 as int
  if (i16 == -1) return null;
  char c16 = (char)i16; // UTF-16
  if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c16)) {
    int low_i16 = input.read(); // low surrogate UTF-16 as int
    if (low_i16 == -1)
      throw new java.io.IOException ("Can not read low surrogate");
    char low_c16 = (char)low_i16;
    int codepoint = Character.toCodePoint(c16, low_c16);
    return new String (Character.toChars(codepoint));
  }
  else 
    return Character.toString(c16);
}
```

But it contains unsafe casts. I have no idea how to avoid them. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by _unsafe casts_? Casting from `int` to `char` will never crash, and because of your `int`s coming from `input.read();` you won't lose any information by the cast.

Comment: @jlordo I mean with *unsafe* a loose of data, because `int` does not fit into `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc of the `read` method [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29):

> Returns: The character read, as an integer in the range **0 to 65535**
>   (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

The `char` primative [is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) "a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a **minimum value of** '`\u0000`' (or **0**) and a **maximum value of** '`\uffff`' (or **65,535 inclusive**)."

(emphasis mine)

It would appear that your two C-style casts are safe.